# logname / who -u / how to get the pid of the current session

Tags: process, session

The command "logname" gives me the name of the login user irrespective of subsequent "su"-calls.
E.g. in current mint, the command "logname" is broken und gives no logname.
I want to get its functinality by other commands.
The output of the command "who -u" contains the desired information in one of its result lines, like:

```
schade   tty7         2019-04-13 10:01 02:41        2674 (:0)
user1    tty8         2019-04-13 10:05 02:41        3518 (:1)
schade   pts/3        2019-04-13 10:33   .          6274 (fd00::eb5d:1659:bda5:8b95)
user2    tty9         2019-04-13 10:34 02:41        6475 (:2)
schade   pts/7        2019-04-13 12:16   .         10727 (fd00::eb5d:1659:bda5:8b95)
```

but in which one?
I should have to find out the pid of my current login (here 2674, not that of the shell) as the second last entry in each line or the computer name as the last entry coded in ":0" to filter it out. How can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On systems running `logind`,

```
loginctl user-status | head -n 1
```

will show the login and uid of the user who logged in to the current session. This works even with `sudo` etc.